# Application.Designer.cs Errors - Can't find assembly properties

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties, namespaces, assemblies

I am helping convert a Visual Basic project to C#. The following is the original VB code in the Application.Designer.cs document:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34014
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Public Sub New()   
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = False
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
            Me.ShutdownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.ePlanSysOman.frmMain
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The following is code that was the result from an online VB to C# converter:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;//I added this in
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;//I added this in

namespace My
{

//NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
// or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
// (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
// Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
//
    internal partial class MyApplication
    {

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        public MyApplication() :     base(global::Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = false;
            this.EnableVisualStyles = true;
            this.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true;
            this.ShutdownStyle = global::Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses;        
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        protected virtual void OnCreateMainForm()//I changed "override" to "virtual" 
        {
            this.MainForm = global::ePlanSysOman.frmMain;
        }
    }
}
```

The properties that are not found are the following:

```
this.IsSingleInstance
this.EnableVisualStyles
this.SaveMySettingsOnExit
this.ShutdownStyle
this.MainForm
```

I looked each one up and I have the correct namespaces and assemblies for them. Two more issues I am having is with:

```
base(global::Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
//I receive the following error: "object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

and

```
global::ePlanSysOman.frmMain
//I receive the following error: 'ePlanSysOman.frmMain' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
```

The VB code is error free. Only the C# code contains errors. I am not too familiar with either languages and any advice to help solve these errors will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @Plutonix So will C# just take care of that stuff by itself, or will I be screwed if I delete Application.Designer.cs?

Comment: VS creates and manages designer files itself - you ought not be editting them directly unless you really, really know what you are doing.  I dont think you need the file at all since it is entirely for implementing that VB App Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VB apps, there is an "Application Framework" which is enabled by default and accessed from **Project -> Properties -> Application**:

[image]

All of the things from you "Not Found" list are part of that FrameWork, except MainForm.  Rather than a `program.cs` being added to the project as in C# to show a form, VB creates an instance of the main form and displays it from designer code.